# Sending user data over part 2

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am seeking some more advice on the way to handle this.

I have got one page with links to each admin member which when clicked takes their display name over. On the second page which is a form it takes that display names and populates the subject field with their display name. I need to grab the email address that is associated to that user too but use that as the email address the form on the second page gets sent to as currently my script can only send it to an email address I hard code into it.

So page one is:

```
<?php
$args1 = array(
 'role' => 'committee',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);
 $committee = get_users($args1);


foreach ($committee as $user) {
echo ' 

    <a href="../contact-form?displayname=' . $user->display_name . '"><b style="font-size:18px;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->job_title .' - </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->display_name .'</td>
    </tr></b></a><br><br>';

 }

?>
```

Page two is:

```
<?php $displayname = $_GET['displayname'];?>

<form role="form" method="post" action="../mailuser.php">  

<div class="form-group">

<input type="hidden" name="displayname" value="<?php echo $displayname ?>">
<input type="text" name="hp" class="hp" value="" alt="if you fill this field out then your email will not be sent">

</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label for="InputName">Your name</label>
<input type="name" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter your name" name="username">
</div>

<div class="form-group">                      
<label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="you@example.com" name="emailFrom">
</div>

<div class="form-group">                             
<label for="InputMsg">Message</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="InputMsg" placeholder="Please begin typing your message..." name="emailMessage"></textarea>   
</div>    

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
</form>
```

And my send script has my email hard coded in as:

$mail->From = 'myemail@dummy.com';

So I need that be variable depending on which person you clicked on in the first place. It needs to be sent to both my hard coded email and also the persons email that is associated to them in the Wordpress user database.

Comment: do you have the display names and email addresses in a database?

Comment: @MikeWillis So the username and email addresses are stored a database but using Wordpress as my backend. So If you take a peek at the first part of my script it shows how I can get access to them and to display them.

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure how get_users worked. In this case why not lookup the email address on page two, using the displayname as the match?

Comment: That is where I am stuck, I thought that would be the most logical way but not sure what the best way to achieve that is?

Comment: Does get_users return the displayname AND the email address? If so, on page two you can do another get_users, loop through the list, find the one with the matching displayname, and pull the email address. Then $mail->To = $matchedEmailAddress; should do the trick

Comment: Yep get_users brings back everything and I can use .$user->whatever this is to show the info I need. How do I get it to match the displayname though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56353/discussion-between-user3725879-and-mike-willis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comment discussion, you should be able to do something along the lines of the following on page two. Be sure to correct my email_address, I'm not sure if that's how get_users returns the email address or not.

```
<?php

$displayname = $_GET['displayname'];

$args1 = array(
 'role' => 'committee',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);
$committee = get_users($args1);

$matchingEmail = false;
foreach ($committee as $user) {
    if ( !$matchingEmail && $user->display_name == $displayname ) {
        // great, we found our match
        $matchingEmail = $user->email_address; // I don't know if email_address is right, double check this and modify if necessary
    }
}

if ( $matchingEmail ) {
    // only proceed if a matching email address is found
    ?>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="../mailuser.php">  

        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="hidden" name="displayname" value="<?php echo $displayname; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="matchingEmail" value="<?php echo $matchingEmail; ?>">
            <input type="text" name="hp" class="hp" value="" alt="if you fill this field out then your email will not be sent">

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputName">Your name</label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter your name" name="username">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">                      
            <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="you@example.com" name="emailFrom">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">                             
            <label for="InputMsg">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="InputMsg" placeholder="Please begin typing your message..." name="emailMessage"></textarea>   
        </div>    

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
    </form>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <p>Something is wrong, I can't find your email address! Please try again.</p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Finally on page three, where you send the email, you can do something like:

```
<?php $mail->addAddress(stripslashes( $_POST["matchingEmail"] ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Ok so was all working fine up until the sending of the mail I get this error:  Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Comment: my mistake, it should have been <?php $mail->To = stripslashes( $_POST["matchingEmail"] ); ?>, please try again

Comment: Are you using PHPMailer? If so $mail->To isn't right, you would use <?php $mail->addAddress(stripslashes($_POST["matchingEmail"])); ?>

Comment: Ok so that worked, I think it tried to send an email to the email field that it sends from too as it bounced. I got once email but bounced the other.

Comment: There must be something else going on, it should only send an email to addresses added by addAddress(). How do we move this to chat?

Comment: Mark, ignore that last email there was a huge delay on the mail server! Works so perfect!